# Accidentally formatted the EFi partition with windows when installing arch

Tags: arch-linux, boot, windows, dual-boot, grub

I was trying to dual boot arch linux with windows 11.

But I accidentally formatted the windows EFI partition and used it as the EFI partition for arch.

Right now I can boot into arch linux but not into windows. Is there any way I can recover the partition and get both windows and arch running again?

Comment: Boot from Windows pendrive/cd and use "automatic recovery" or `bootrec`: https://www.easeus.com/partition-master/repair-windows-11-uefi-bootloader.html

but it has nothing to do with Unix

Comment: (1) Use Grub's OS-prober. (2) Use a usb stick with Ikki Boot.iso (2.6 GB) or super_grub2_disk_hybrid.iso 'burnt' to it to boot to any operating system installed on your system. (3) Add the menuentry from windows manual to Grub.cfg (menuentry "Windows 10" --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-efi-F024-2799' {
 insmod part_gpt
 insmod fat
 if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
   search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root  F024-2799
 else
   search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root F024-2799
 fi
 chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi)